# SQL Server 2008 storage configuration issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008. I learned from this link that NAS storage is not enabled by default. Any ideas how to enable it?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261/en-us

Quote from this link,

**on the network, then by default, the disk storage system is not supported as a location for SQL Server databases.**

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting trace flag 1807 will tell SQL to bypass the check that it does to see if the files are on a network share.  Have a look at [**this KB article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261).

Why you would do this, though, is really the question.  It's really bad news for SQL.

Comment: How to set the trace flag? I did not see any command to enable this from the Url.

Comment: Thanks, question answered. I met with a further issue, which is how to set username and password for the network shared location in SQL Server. I post this question here, any solutions?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171759/sql-server-2008-create-database-issue